Adding alternative labels for Voice Access in Android
I'm wondering if it is possible to add alternative labels for voice access, to help users when interacting with items that may not contain text.
For example, an icon for a shopping trolley could have buy or purchase.
I can't see this in the Android API but want to see if I'm missing anything.
